# How to remap ci$

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-vimtex, custom-text-object

I am using the plugin vimtex. It offers the functionality (from the introduction of its documentation)

> - Text objects
>
>   - `ic` `ac` Commands
>   - `id` `ad` Delimiters
>   - `ie` `ae` LaTeX environments
>   - `i$` `a$` Inline math structures
>   - `iP` `aP` Sections

This means that with `ci$` I can delete everyithing between two `$`-signs. I would like to remap this to `cim`, because it is easier to type. However `nnoremap cim ci$` has no effect. What can I do instead?

I notice that this has probably nothing to do with vimtex, but I don't know any other example to illustrate my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `i$` is a mapping itself (defined by the vimtex plug-in), you need a *recursive* mapping to be able to use `i$` as part of the expansion of your mapping.

So this should work:

```
nmap cim ci$
```

But you can also create an operator-pending mode mapping for `im`, in which case that would work with other operations such as `dim` or `yim` and other built-in or custom operations that take a motion:

```
omap im i$
```

If vimtex also defines `i$` in Visual mode (which is a common pattern), you might want to create the mapping for your alias in Visual mode as well:

```
xmap im i$
```

Finally, you may want to define these mappings only for `tex` files, so consider adding these commands to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` (so it's loaded only for files with FileType `tex`, and only after the vimtex plug-in has been loaded.)

Finally, you want to use `<buffer>` to make your mappings local to your buffer, so they're loaded for buffers of that filetype and do not leak into other filetypes:

```
omap <buffer> im i$
xmap <buffer> im i$
```

Finally, you might want to modify the `b:undo_ftplugin` variable to remove these mappings if the filetype-related plug-in actions need to be undone. See `:help undo_ftplugin` for more details on that.

If you simply want `im` as an alias to `i$` in all cases (assuming other plug-ins might have their own definition for `i$`), then global mappings for it might be acceptable, they certainly work.

Answer (score 2):

You can also put the following in your `.vimrc`:

```
    xmap dsm <plug>(vimtex-env-delete-math)
    xmap csm <plug>(vimtex-env-change-math)
    xmap am  <plug>(vimtex-a$)
    xmap im  <plug>(vimtex-i$)

    omap dsm <plug>(vimtex-env-delete-math)
    omap csm <plug>(vimtex-env-change-math)
    omap am  <plug>(vimtex-a$)
    omap im  <plug>(vimtex-i$)
```

This plugs the corresponding functions defined by `vimtex` directly to `dsm, csm, am, im`. With these mappings `a$, i$` etc won't work anymor. Not sure how to make both `a$` and `am` work (without making vim wait when single `a` or `i` is pressed in normal mode), but I am guessing you don't need both of them to work.